# Discover other devices while connected?

Tags: bluetooth

Can a bluetooth adapter detect for other discoverable devices while it's already connected to another device? It seems to me that it detects only in the STANDBY state, so being connected to another device puts it in some other non-unconnected state. I could be wrong, of course.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it can discover while being connected.
It is typically done by time sharing the link between the 2 procedures, most devices handle this very efficiently with no observed impact at the application.